# Use email and password to authenticate user in LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am new to LDAP and I am working on an application using LDAP for authentication.
Is there a way to authenticate user in LDAP using email & password?
or I can only accomplish that by:

1. Obtain user's DN by the given email.
2. Bind user with DN & password.

is there a configuration option that can allow LDAP use some other fields to authenticate user?

Comment: You have to follow the two steps you stated.

Comment: @EJP, OK, thanks a lot.

Comment: For the bind you need the DN of thr user and the password associated with it. So it's not a single attribute. That's why you need the 2 steps. First find the DN using the email and then use that DN for login. Some directories (like AD) though allow usage of email-address. But that's NOT ldap!

Answer (score -1):

If you plan for your application to use a directory service as an external user store, welcome to the world of directory enabled applications.  It's not mandatory for your application to establish an LDAP session for a user.  Usually, you'll have a service account your application will use to establish an LDAP session with the directory service.  When a user logs in to your application your authentication module will lookup the user entry using some unique attribute (uid, mail, ...) so a simple authentication (comparison of password hashes) can be done.

This very much depends on your infrastructure.

EDIT: [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-ldap-authenticators-password) refers to this technique as password comparison authentication.

Comment: No. The application must attempt a bind as the user after looking him up. The LDAP server is the one to check the password and do anything ele that is associated with the bind. That's what it's there for. Otherise there is no opportunity for the server to check for password expiration, account lockout, password must be reset, too many password failures, etc.

Comment: User accounts in my LDAP directory (~200k, not AD) are mostly provisioned from a metadirectory, some are self-serviced.  None does a BIND according to my log files, only service accounts show up. Our SAP consultants seem to like it that way.  It's just one way to do it, I guess, and IT security seems to have approved.  Mind you, connections are costly, properly conducted searches are cheap.  Should I worry? ;-)

Comment: You've got a point there with policy enforcement.  On my site it's not wanted, all the nifty features are implemented by the authentication module which uses my directory as a user store.  It depends, as I said.  I sure can ramp up my replication topology to cope with thousands of short lived user sessions, but for now I don't have to.  Implementation should follow requirements analysis.  We are not consulting here, it's more like idea fishing.

Comment: Follow EJP's advise.

Comment: @marabu So in your particular situation with your specific lack of password policies your specific IT security guys seem to have approved this error, assuming they have even noticed it. That doesn't make it right for everybody. It doesn't even make it right for you. It is a programming error and it is also an IT security error: they should have noticed it and they should have objected to it.